# Standard and fasted integer equivalency

Tags: c, language-lawyer

The standard gives the following minimum bit widths for standard unsigned types:

```
unsigned char >= 8
unsigned short >= 16
unsigned int >= 16
unsigned long >= 32
unsigned long long >= 64
```

(Implicitly, by specifying minimum maximal values).

Does that imply the following equivalencies?

```
unsigned char == uint_fast8_t
unsigned short == uint_fast16_t
unsigned int == uint_fast16_t
unsigned long == uint_fast32_t
unsigned long long == uint_fast64_t
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, because the size of the default "primitive data types" are picked by the compiler to be something *convenient* for the given system. Convenient meaning easy to work with for various reasons: integer range, the size of the other integer types, backwards compatibility etc. It is not necessarily picked to be the fastest possible.

For example, in practice `unsigned int` has the size 32 on a 32 bit system, but also size 32 on a 64 bit system. But on the 64 bit system, `uint_fast32_t` could be 64 bits.

Just look at the most commonly used sizes in practice for `unsigned char` versus `uint_fast8_t`:

```
Data bus   unsigned char   uint_fast8_t
8 bit      8 bit           8 bit
16 bit     8 bit           16 bit
32 bit     8 bit           32 bit
64 bit     8 bit           32/64 bit
```

This is so, because for convenience we need a byte type to work with. Yet the optimizing compiler may very well place this `unsigned char` byte at an aligned address and read it as a 32 bit access, so it might perform optimizations despite the actual size of the data type.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is an answer to the question but (at least  in `glibc`), `int_fastx_t` and `uint_fastx_t` are `typedef`ed depending of the word size:

```
/* Fast types.  */

/* Signed.  */
typedef signed char     int_fast8_t;
#if __WORDSIZE == 64
typedef long int        int_fast16_t;
typedef long int        int_fast32_t;
typedef long int        int_fast64_t;
#else
typedef int         int_fast16_t;
typedef int         int_fast32_t;
__extension__
typedef long long int       int_fast64_t;
#endif

/* Unsigned.  */
typedef unsigned char       uint_fast8_t;
#if __WORDSIZE == 64
typedef unsigned long int   uint_fast16_t;
typedef unsigned long int   uint_fast32_t;
typedef unsigned long int   uint_fast64_t;
#else
typedef unsigned int        uint_fast16_t;
typedef unsigned int        uint_fast32_t;
__extension__
typedef unsigned long long int  uint_fast64_t;
#endif
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically you're right, but not de jure.
int is meant to be the "natural" integer type for the system. In fact it is usually 32 bit on 32 and 64 bit systems, and 16 bits on small systems, because 64 bit ints would break too many interfaces. So int is essentially the fast_32_t.
However it's not guaranteed. And the smaller types like 8 and 16 bits might well have faster 32 bit equivalents. However in practise using int will likely give you the fastest code.